# git merge forked repo to local repo

Tags: git, github, merge

I have made a lot of changes to a known repo on Github to fit my current needs. After a while I had noticed that the repo had received a lot of bug fixes I would like to put in my local repo.
So I forked the updated repo and cloned it, and then put all my personal changes in that local repo and pushed it to my fork, in order to be able to merge the updated one with my changes.
However, after trying to fetch from upstream/pull from upstream/merge, nothing really happens. I always get these messages:

git pull upstream develop
From https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController
 * branch            develop    -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.

git merge upstream/develop
Already up-to-date.

My local changes have been committed and pushed to my forked repo, and now basically I am just trying to merge the master develop branch with my forked develop branch, but as you can see to no avail.

Any idea on how to proceed?
Thanks

Comment: Seems like this. You're merging branch A into branch B, and B already has all changes from A.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Yeah, that makes sense, as I just cloned it. Do you have any clue however on how I can achieve a merge between all of my changes and the new updated repo?

Comment: I'll try to make an instruction. Do you really mean to pull from develop and not master? That is, develop seems to me the latest, but unstable release.

Comment: Do you want to preserve the history of your own commits?

Comment: ` a lot of changes to a known repo on Github to fit my current needs` - did you make them in a local repo or just in an unversioned project?

Comment: Thanks for the comments @NickVolynkin. I made all my changes up until now in an unversioned project, not using Git, and now I just forked the updated Git and put my changes in there to try and merge both branches

Comment: Ha ) Just made and instruction for a versioned project. Will add some changes.

Comment: @NickVolynkin never got an answer from you, any insights?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have a local repo where you did your improvements to the code. The following is done in your local repo.

```
# you can rename your branch in advance, in order to avoid confusion about branch names.
git branch -m my_development

git remote add upstream https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController.git
git fetch upstream
git branch --track develop upstream/develop
```

Now you have got a local branch `develop`, a complete copy of `upstream/develop`. You can merge `my_develop` into `develop`:

```
git checkout develop
git merge my_develop
```

You will probably have merge conflicts on files which were changed both locally by yourself, and remotely by developers of the project. For each Git will offer you a file, combining changes from both. It may be convenient to initiate a merge from your IDE, to be able to edit your code in it instead of vim editor.